# Magento 2.2: Block disappears when setting a class

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

I have a strange issue with Magento 2.2 that's making me bang my head against a wall.

I've got the following files in a custom module:

PallidVisions/Swatches/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- TODO: take this stuff out of the head and put it into the body -->
    <head>
        <css src="PallidVisions_Swatches::css/swatches.css" />
        <link src="PallidVisions_Swatches::js/swatch-modifications.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block class="PallidVisions\Swatches\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.options.data" template="PallidVisions_Swatches::swatch-data.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

PallidVisions/Swatches/view/frontend/templates/swatch-data.phtml:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

PallidVisions/Swatches/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Overrides Magento\Swatches catalog super product configurable
 * part block, modifying it so that out of stock options will show up in
 * the list of options, but be labeled as such and be disabled.
 *
 * Based on the solution posted here:
 * https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/magento-2-2-how-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product
 *
 * This was written for Magento 2.2.5 and might need modification to be
 * compatible with future releases.
 */
namespace PallidVisions\Swatches\Block\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product as CatalogProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data as SwatchData;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\SwatchAttributesProvider;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\Format;

class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable {

    // Defined in the parent of this parent's class, but since it's private and
    // I need it, I have to implement it again here.
    private $localeFormat;
    private $variationPrices;

    // List of all associated products, including those that are out of stock
    protected $childProducts;

    /*************************************************************************/

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        Data $helper,
        CatalogProduct $catalogProduct,
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ConfigurableAttributeData $configurableAttributeData,
        SwatchData $swatchHelper,
        Media $swatchMediaHelper,
        array $data = [],
        SwatchAttributesProvider $swatchAttributesProvider = null
    ) {

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $arrayUtils,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $helper,
            $catalogProduct,
            $currentCustomer,
            $priceCurrency,
            $configurableAttributeData,
            $swatchHelper,
            $swatchMediaHelper,
            $data,
            $swatchAttributesProvider
        );

        $this->localeFormat = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Format::class);
        $this->variationPrices = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Variations\Prices::class
        );

        $this->childProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($this->getProduct());
    }

    /*************************************************************************/

    // Overrides Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig
    public function getJsonConfig() {

        $store = $this->getCurrentStore();
        $currentProduct = $this->getProduct();

        $options = $this->helper->getOptions($currentProduct, $this->childProducts);
        $attributesData = $this->configurableAttributeData->getAttributesData($currentProduct, $options);

        $config = [
            'attributes' => $attributesData['attributes'],
            'template' => str_replace('%s', '<%- data.price %>', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
            'currencyFormat' => $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat(),
            'optionPrices' => $this->getOptionPrices(),
            'optionStock' => $this->getOptionStocks(),
            'priceFormat' => $this->localeFormat->getPriceFormat(),
            'prices' => $this->variationPrices->getFormattedPrices($this->getProduct()->getPriceInfo()),
            'productId' => $currentProduct->getId(),
            'chooseText' => __('Choose an Option...'),
            'images' => $this->getOptionImages(),
            'index' => isset($options['index']) ? $options['index'] : [],
        ];

        if ($currentProduct->hasPreconfiguredValues() && !empty($attributesData['defaultValues'])) {
            $config['defaultValues'] = $attributesData['defaultValues'];
        }

        $config = array_merge($config, $this->_getAdditionalConfig());

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }

    /*************************************************************************/

    // Overrides Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getOptionImages
    // This function is exactly the same with the exception of where the product
    // data comes from.
    protected function getOptionImages() {

        $images = [];

        foreach ($this->childProducts as $product) {

            $productImages = $this->helper->getGalleryImages($product) ?: [];

            foreach ($productImages as $image) {

                $images[$product->getId()][] = [
                        'thumb' => $image->getData('small_image_url'),
                        'img' => $image->getData('medium_image_url'),
                        'full' => $image->getData('large_image_url'),
                        'caption' => $image->getLabel(),
                        'position' => $image->getPosition(),
                        'isMain' => $image->getFile() == $product->getImage(),
                        'type' => str_replace('external-', '', $image->getMediaType()),
                        'videoUrl' => $image->getVideoUrl(),
                ];
            }
        }

        return $images;
    }

    /*************************************************************************/

    // Overrides Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getOptionPrices.
    // This function is exactly the same with the exception of where the product
    // data comes from.
    protected function getOptionPrices() {

        $prices = [];

        foreach ($this->childProducts as $product) {

            $tierPrices = [];
            $priceInfo = $product->getPriceInfo();
            $tierPriceModel =  $priceInfo->getPrice('tier_price');
            $tierPricesList = $tierPriceModel->getTierPriceList();

            foreach ($tierPricesList as $tierPrice) {

                $tierPrices[] = [
                    'qty' => $this->localeFormat->getNumber($tierPrice['price_qty']),
                    'price' => $this->localeFormat->getNumber($tierPrice['price']->getValue()),
                    'percentage' => $this->localeFormat->getNumber(
                        $tierPriceModel->getSavePercent($tierPrice['price'])
                    ),
                ];
            }

                $prices[$product->getId()] = [

                    'oldPrice' => [
                        'amount' => $this->localeFormat->getNumber(
                            $priceInfo->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                        ),
                    ],

                    'basePrice' => [
                        'amount' => $this->localeFormat->getNumber(
                            $priceInfo->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
                        ),
                    ],

                    'finalPrice' => [
                        'amount' => $this->localeFormat->getNumber(
                            $priceInfo->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                        ),
                    ],

                    'tierPrices' => $tierPrices,
                ];
        }

        return $prices;
    }

    /*************************************************************************/

    protected function getOptionStocks() {

        $stocks = [];
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
        $stockObject=$objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

        foreach ($this->childProducts as $product) {          
            $productStockObj = $stockObject->getStockItem($product->getId());
            $isInStock = !$productStockObj['manage_stock'] | $productStockObj['is_in_stock'] ? '1' : '0';
            $stocks[$product->getId()] = ['stockStatus' => $isInStock];
        }

        return $stocks;
    }
}
```

If I remove the class="..." attribute from the block element in my layout xml, the block renders, and I see the div from my template inside my source. If, however, I specify the class, the block silently disappears. I get no errors to help my diagnose why it isn't working. It just doesn't render. I've tried changing the class name to a class that doesn't exist, and that made Magento throw an error, so it's seeing the class in Configurable.php. It's just not rendering for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Please check out what template you got in toHtml() method: \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable::toHtml()

Comment: That was the problem. The template was being specified in the class, so my setting in the layout was ignored. I'm still new to Magento, so things like this always catch my by surprise. Thank you!